# Got error 422 with vuex (dispatch) in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, fetch, vuex

I got an error :

`422 (Unprocessable Content)`

when I tried to post a data in register form

I have this in my Register.vue

```
  methods: {
    register() {
      this.$store.dispatch('register', {
        firstname: this.firstname,
        lastname: this.lastname,
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
      });
    },
  },
};
```

and in my vuex

```
  actions: {
    register(credentials) {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        dataType: 'json',
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
      };
      console.log(credentials);
      return fetch('http://localhost/api/users', requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
    },
  }
```

Anyone know where I'm wrong ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't return twice if the request is good.

```
  actions: {
    register(credentials) {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        dataType: 'json', // not needed 
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
      };
      console.log(credentials);
      return fetch('http://localhost/api/users', requestOptions) // first time
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json; // second time
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
    },
  }
```

Also use async/await. I'd do

```
  actions: {
    async register(credentials) {
    
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        dataType: 'json',
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
      };
    
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost/api/users', requestOptions);
    }

    return res.json();
  }
```

And in the `Register.vue`

```
  methods: {
    register() {
      this.$store.dispatch('register', {
        firstname: this.firstname,
        lastname: this.lastname,
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
      }).then(data => {
        console.log(data)
      }).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
    });
  },
};
```

Also you can put it in try/cache etc. It's up to you.

Check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options), it well explained.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer ! fetch is working but I still got error 422 . It's look like my data doesnt send to backend, maybe it's because of dispatch?

Comment: Well then it's not a FE issue. Check your logs for more info, what is happening. If the data is being processed on the BE part.

Comment: I see many thanks for your help !!